# My Filebeat configuration can't listen to my logs inside my Kubernetes pods

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have web app service that run in go and produce a log that I stored inside `/var/logs/app/app.log`. This service is running inside a Kubernetes pods. And I have another pods that running Filebeat to listen to logs produced by app service. But my Filebeat doesn't seems can listen to the logs produced by apps.

This is my config map for filebeat deployment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          templates:
            - config:
                - type: container
                  paths:
                    - /var/logs/app/*.log                  

    processors:
      - decode_json_fields:
          fields: ['message']
          target: json
      - rename:
          fields:
            - from: "url"
              to: "url_data"
          ignore_missing: false
          fail_on_error: true

    cloud.id: ${CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth : ${CLOUD_AUTH}
```

And this is my deployment config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
        - name: filebeat
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.8.1
          args: [
            "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
            "-e",
          ]
          env:
            - name: CLOUD_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: filebeat-secret
                  key: cloud.id
            - name: CLOUD_AUTH
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: filebeat-secret
                  key: cloud.auth
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              readOnly: true
              subPath: filebeat.yml
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0640
            name: filebeat-config
```

I expect filebeat can listen custom log instead of docker logs. Where did I go wrong that filebeat can't listen to my app logs.

Comment: Have you already tried to enter in the filebeat container? Moreover, have you tried to put in the deployment the app and the filebeat as sidecar?

Comment: Hi @kiggyttass, may I know what you mean by already tried to enter in filebeat container? Also, I have already tried to put the app and filebeat in the same deployment. After deploying I can't find any running filebeat if i'm using filebeat as a sidecar. If you see my deployment config or configmap. Do you see where I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: for 'enter in the container' i mean, if it's running, to run the command 'kubectl exec -it filebeat -- bash' and navigate the filesystem to check if your volume was mounted. For the sidecar question, you could edit the question adding the deployment with the sidecar  also,if you like

Comment: @Dehoer For the sidecar question, you could edit the question adding the deployment with the sidecar also, if you like.